# Get AWS SNS confirm subscription token and pass it as a parameter to API

Tags: java, amazon-sns, aws-java-sdk

I was trying to write a code to subscribe an end point to a topic in amazon simple notification service.
After subscribing a confirmation mail was sent to the end point email id.

```
ConfigurationSet configurationSet = new ConfigurationSet().withName(configSetName);
CreateConfigurationSetRequest createConfigurationSetRequest = new CreateConfigurationSetRequest().withConfigurationSet(configurationSet);
amazonSES.createConfigurationSet(createConfigurationSetRequest);
CreateTopicRequest createTopicRequest = new CreateTopicRequest(topicName);
CreateTopicResult createTopicResult = amazonSNS.createTopic(createTopicRequest);
SubscribeRequest subscribeRequest = new SubscribeRequest(createTopicResult.getTopicArn(), "email", endPoint);
SubscribeResult subscribeResult = amazonSNS.subscribe(subscribeRequest);
```

To confirm the subscription there is 2 ways
 1. Go to mail and click 'Confirm subscription'
 2. Use ConfirmSubscription API like below

```
public void confirmSubscription(String token, String topicArn) {
     ConfirmSubscriptionRequest confirmSubscriptionRequest = new ConfirmSubscriptionRequest()
                .withTopicArn(topicArn)
                .withToken(token)
                .withAuthenticateOnUnsubscribe("ConfirmSubscriptionResult 
    ConfirmSubscriptionResult confirmSubscriptionResult = amazonSNS.confirmSubscription(confirmSubscriptionRequest);
}
```

In the second method we need a token which is generated when we click the 'Confirm Subscription' link.
So i need to get that token to pass as a parameter in confirmSubscription() method.
Is there any way for that ?
Can we set to call a rest api when we click the confirm subscription from the mail ?
Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the way I retrieved the token was use code to get into the email sent to the subscribed user, and pull the Token from the url link. A bit convoluted, but it worked.